# P2P getHeaders message - how to get block locator hashes

Tags: peers, peer-discovery, p2p

I'm trying to build my own block explorer
So that I need to use p2p bitcoin protocol. For that I'm using [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/tree/master/peer) (golang) lib.

According to [bitcoin book](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch08.asciidoc#address_propagation) I have to send **version** message (and receive **verack** message back) to init the connection, then I will send **getheaders** message in cycle.

Now, imagine I am a new peer and want to download all the blockchain (actually I want to receive block hashes with **getheaders** (2000 per tick) and for each block hash I want to receive a block itself to process it and put blocks data in my mongo database)

If I am new peer in the network, how should I send first (and next) **getheaders** message, I don't quite understand where should I get **block locator hashes** and how to form the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block locator hashes are just the hashes of various blocks that you already have. As a new peer, the only block that you will have is the genesis block (the genesis block must be hard coded into your software). So you just send a `getheaders` message that only contains the hash of the genesis block.